# How to view my last transaction in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, rollback

I updated only one column in the table. Now I must update it to the previous value. How can I view the previous value? I disconnected from the session and now `dba_2pc_pending` returned 0 rows.

Answer (score 2):

If [flashback](http://psoug.org/reference/flash_query.html) queries are enabled in your system you can try those. Otherwise you can be out of luck.